# This project needs to be migrated xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, migration

I built a Xamarin simple app project for android device.
It's compiled and also run on my device, whereas after some times I faced an error.
the error is:

> "This project needs to be migrated."

and also I couldn't create new android Xamarin project. 
In fact, it's disappeared from new project section.
What can I do??

[image]

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5963).

Answer (score 4):

My issue was that "Mobile development with .NET" was not selected/installed in the Visual Studio Installer for VS2019 (coulda sworn I selected that when I moved from 2017 to 2019, but whatever).  Once selected and installed, the migration warnings disappeared and I could run the projects.

Comment: Yep was missing critical Xamarin components, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when running the visual studio in safe mode, suggesting that an extension is disabled/missing.